# Check transaction per block in Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, block

what is bitcoin-cli command for checking how many transaction per block ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

[`getblockstats`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblockstats.html)

> ```
>   "txs" : n,                   (numeric) The number of transactions (including coinbase)
> ```

---

Example

```
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon> bitcoin-cli getblockcount
627251

C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon> bitcoin-cli getblockstats 627251 | findstr /C:"\"txs\":"
  "txs": 2103,
```

The full output contains lots of other information

```
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon> bitcoin-cli getblockstats 627251
{
  "avgfee": 8359,
  "avgfeerate": 17,
  "avgtxsize": 571,
  "blockhash": "000000000000000000070ab39c953fd599b27da2c171476d2b2e8533484130bd",
  "feerate_percentiles": [
    7,
    7,
    8,
    25,
    30
  ],
  "height": 627251,
  "ins": 6108,
  "maxfee": 1598037,
  "maxfeerate": 387,
  "maxtxsize": 99011,
  "medianfee": 4007,
  "mediantime": 1587620811,
  "mediantxsize": 249,
  "minfee": 162,
  "minfeerate": 1,
  "mintxsize": 188,
  "outs": 4844,
  "subsidy": 1250000000,
  "swtotal_size": 550012,
  "swtotal_weight": 1383607,
  "swtxs": 893,
  "time": 1587623122,
  "total_out": 403374241843,
  "total_size": 1202103,
  "total_weight": 3991971,
  "totalfee": 17572435,
  "txs": 2103,
  "utxo_increase": -1264,
  "utxo_size_inc": -94315
}
```